# regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex

How to validate an expression for a single dot character?
For example if I have an expression `"trjb....fsf..ib.bi."` then it should return only dots at index 15 and 18.  If I use Pattern `p=Pattern.compile("(\\.)+");` I get

```
4 ....
11 ..
15 .
18 .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
String input = "trjb....fsf..ib.bi.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\.]\\.([^\\.]|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(" " + input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start());
}
```

The extra space in front of the input does two things:

1. Allows for a `.` to be detected as the first character of the input string
2. Offsets the `matcher.start()` by one to account for the character in front of the matched `.`

Result is:

```
15
18
```

Answer (score 2):

add a blank at the beginning and at the end of the string and then use the pattern

```
"[^\\.]\\.[^\\.]"
```

Comment: And add a space at the end too... :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use negative lookarounds .

Something like `Pattern.compile("(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)");`

Comment: Amal,Could u pl explain the pattern.I don get the use of <!

Comment: the expression matches for a '.' character not preceded by a '.' and not followed by a '.'.   Refer [http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try

`Pattern.compile("(?<=[^\\.])\\.(?=[^\\.])")`

or even better...

`Pattern.compile("(?<![\\.])\\.(?![\\.])")`

This uses [negative lookaround.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

`(?<![\\.])` => *not* preceeded by a `.`

`\\.`        => a `.`

`(?![\\.])`  => *not* followed by a `.`